# Phatch no longer in repositories, is there another safe location for ubuntu?

Tags: photo-management

Phatch no longer in repositories, is there another safe location for Ubuntu?
I cannot find it in synaptic and no results in Terminal.

Comment: last stable version is from 2010, no wonder that Ubuntu doesn't have it in the repos anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Unofficial snap is available: https://snapcraft.io/phatch-gui To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo snap install phatch-gui
```

Comment: This is the easiest way to install it in new Ubuntu versions.

Answer (score 1):

As of now Phatch is available for 14.04 and 16.04. But you can download its file from [Phatch Download (DEB, RPM, TXZ)](https://pkgs.org/download/phatch) and install it using:

```
sudo dpkg -i phatch_0.2.7.1-3.1_all.deb
```

or right click on downloaded and open with *'Software Install'*.

Answer (score 1):

The packages are available in older LTS releases - 14.04 and 16.04 - see [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=Phatch).
You need to get all necessary dependencies with:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pillow/python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.3_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/phatch/phatch-cli_0.2.7.1-3.1_all.deb
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/phatch/phatch_0.2.7.1-3.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb ./phatch*.deb
```

And you will get it working:

```
$ phatch --version
Phatch 0.2.7
```

Comment: `wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/pillow/python-imaging_3.1.2-0ubuntu1.1_all.deb` ends up with error but you can download python-imaging .deb from here: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-security/+archive/ubuntu/ppa/+build/12108750